# Rotate Vector in javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, vector, rotation

Sorry as I know this has been brought up before but I am struggling to get this program to draw a star on the canvas. The vector not only points in the wrong direction but also shrinks in size.

I realise that arrays would probably be quicker than objects for the vectors (?) but it is to keep the program as readable as possible. IMHO vector.x is clearer than vector[0]. Probably a matter of taste but I am trying to keep the code as clear as possible for learners.

Thanks in advance.

```
    <canvas id="canvas" height="600px" width="1000px">

    </canvas>

    <script>

        draw();

        function draw() {
                var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

                var currentPoint={x: 500, y: 300}; //start point
                var moveDist = 300;
                var turnAngle = 144;
                var repetitions = 5;
                var turnAngleRadians = turnAngle * (Math.PI/180)
                var moveVector = {x:moveDist, y:0}; //start facing right

                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
                for(i=0;i<repetitions;i++){
                    moveVector = updateMV(moveVector, turnAngleRadians);
                    currentPoint.x = currentPoint.x + moveVector.x;
                    currentPoint.y = currentPoint.y + moveVector.y;
                    ctx.lineTo(currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
                }
                ctx.stroke();
            }

        function updateMV(moveVector, turnAngleRadians){
            var x2, y2
            x2 =    Math.cos(turnAngleRadians) * moveVector.x - Math.sin(turnAngleRadians) * moveVector.y;
            y2 =    Math.sin(turnAngleRadians) * moveVector.x - Math.cos(turnAngleRadians) * moveVector.y;
            moveVector.x = x2;
            moveVector.y = y2;
            return moveVector
        }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula for y2 is wrong it should be +

`y2 = Math.sin(turnAngleRadians) * moveVector.x + Math.cos(turnAngleRadians) * moveVector.y;`

```js
       draw();

        function draw() {
                var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

                var currentPoint={x: 500, y: 300}; //start point
                var moveDist = 300;
                var turnAngle = 144;
                var repetitions = 5;
                var turnAngleRadians = turnAngle * (Math.PI/180)
                var moveVector = {x:moveDist, y:0}; //start facing right

                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
                for(i=0;i<repetitions;i++){
                    moveVector = updateMV(moveVector, turnAngleRadians);
                    currentPoint.x = currentPoint.x + moveVector.x;
                    currentPoint.y = currentPoint.y + moveVector.y;
                    ctx.lineTo(currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
                }
                ctx.stroke();
            }

        function updateMV(moveVector, turnAngleRadians){
            var x2, y2
            x2 =    Math.cos(turnAngleRadians) * moveVector.x - Math.sin(turnAngleRadians) * moveVector.y;
            y2 =    Math.sin(turnAngleRadians) * moveVector.x + Math.cos(turnAngleRadians) * moveVector.y;
            moveVector.x = x2;
            moveVector.y = y2;
            return moveVector
        }
```

```html
    <canvas id="canvas" height="600px" width="1000px">

    </canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us make this simple.

Let's say that we have a star, and we name the five points (points of a star, not necessarily the 10 geometric points) starting from the top going clockwise points A, B, C, D, E. And we would like to start on line BE

We will now make a simple upright star, in which each line's length is 200.
It would be a vector, of angle 72° and magnitude 200, starting on a point (50,500).

But first we must learn on drawing vectors. We make a function `drawVector`, then make the star, where each angle is 36°, then apply it recursively.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    vector = {x: 50, y: 500, deg: 0},
    length = 200;
function drawVector(degrees, magnitude) {
    var rad = degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
    var nextX = vector.x + Math.cos(rad) * magnitude;
    var nextY = vector.y - Math.sin(rad) * magnitude;
    currentAngle = degrees
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(vector.x, vector.y);
    ctx.lineTo(nextX, nextY);
    ctx.stroke();
    vector.x = nextX;
    vector.y = nextY;
    vector.deg = degrees;
}
drawVector(72, 200);
drawVector(180 + vector.deg + 36, 200);
drawVector(180 + vector.deg + 36, 200);
drawVector(180 + vector.deg + 36, 200);
drawVector(180 + vector.deg + 36, 200);
```

Note: `180 + vector.deg` simply makes the start of the next point the same as the first one. You can try to remove each of the `drawVector(180...` to see this.

Comment: You can pretty much factor out the code... I was just too lazy too do it

Answer (score 0):

Such a daft wee error. Thanks for your help hmpphep.

Solved it by changing the transformation calculation for y2 to:

```
y2 =    Math.sin(turnAngleRadians) * moveVector.x + Math.cos(turnAngleRadians) * moveVector.y;
```